# How do I change this indexing file via serial into a parallel one?

Tags: python, distributed-system

I have this code to index all of my file. It's working really well and I used python to code it but as you can see, it's serial. Basically it takes too much time to finish. Approx. 60 seconds. Supposedly, it should be able to run faster in parallel but I don't really know what to do from this point on. Any help or tips are appreciated, thank you.

```
import os
import time

start = time.time()
handle = open("test.txt", "w")

rootDir = '/'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for fname in fileList:
        handle.write("%s\n" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirName, fname)).encode('utf-8'))

handle.close()
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: Who makes this supposition, and what support have they given for it? Do you _have_ to use Python? There are UNIX utilities that will provide the same functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Python for this. I tried some ways but I hit the wall.